# 'System.DateTimeOffset' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0

Tags: winforms, datetimeoffset

My Windows Form application (created in Visual Studio 2008 using C#) is distributed across our company and runs on 50+ PCs with no issues.

Yesterday, I had to install it on an old PC running WinXP. My Visual Studio 2008 Setup project prompted to install the .Net Framework 3.5 SP1. We installed that, rebooted, then continued the installation.

After installation, I turned the old machine off, waited about 5 seconds, then turned it back on.

When I attempted to run the application, I got the Unhandled exception: **"Could not load type 'System.DateTimeOffset' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5**... blah, blah, blah.

[image: Screen Shot of error]

1. Why didn't the 3.5 SP1 install the `DateTimeOffset` feature?
2. Why is the application trying to load this from `mscorlib version 2.0`?
3. I did a search for the keyword `DateTimeOffset`, but it does not exist anywhere in my project. Is this a part of `DateTime` (i.e. `DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)`)?

Here's a copy of the full blown exception:

```
   See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.DateTimeOffset' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
   at System.ComponentModel.ReflectTypeDescriptionProvider.get_IntrinsicTypeConverters()
   at System.ComponentModel.ReflectTypeDescriptionProvider.ReflectedTypeData.GetConverter(Object instance)
   at System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.TypeDescriptionNode.DefaultTypeDescriptor.System.ComponentModel.ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetConverter()
   at System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(Type type)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.GetItemText(Object item)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.NativeAdd(Object item)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCreate(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Suite
    Assembly Version: 2.2.21.30536
    Win32 Version: 2.2.21
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Aaon%20Coil%20Products,%20Inc/ACP%20Software%20Suite/Suite.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 3.5.0.0
    Win32 Version: 3.5.30729.1 built by: SP
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
Accessibility
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
AcpFormHeader
    Assembly Version: 1.0.5.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.5
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Aaon%20Coil%20Products,%20Inc/ACP%20Software%20Suite/AcpFormHeader.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:


    


When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Comment: you may reinstall the .NET Framework version
check this: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-windows_programs/systemtypeloadexception-could-not-load-type/dddfe9d7-8684-47bd-8a67-b19418fe65fc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Good question. The installation appears to have been faulty.
2. Because .NET 3.5 uses the 2.0 runtime, as does .NET 3.0.
3. No, it isn't. It is a completely separate structure (see on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx)). There must be some component that *is* using it, possibly a third party assembly.

Comment: Both answers are correct (I think - I can't get our Administrator to break from his tasks to come help us uninstall and reinstall), but this answer showed up first.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)
> ```

Something went seriously wrong during the install.  Revision 42 was the original .NET 2.0 release.  The trace also shows 2.0.50727.3053, that's a good one.  Right now, the machine has a mix-match of assembly versions.  The exception is indeed expected with that.  No idea of course how this happened, I'm guessing a bad 3.5 install on top of an existing 2.0 install.  Or you forgot to reboot the machine after installing.

Comment: This is more technically correct in the answer, but I'm awarding Oded because his post basically said the same thing and it was first. No offense, I hope.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem today. I was inserting the values in a DataVisualization.Charting.Series this way

```
MaSerie.Points.AddXY(x, y)
```

I change my code for this and the DateTimeOffset error disappear

```
MaSerie.Points.Add(New DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint(x, y))
```